# StreamTokenizer doesn't treat + as word

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

In code

```
switch(token){

    case StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF:
        eof = true;
        break;
    case StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER:
        double value = tokenizer.nval;
        operands.add(value);
        break;
    case StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD:
        operate(tokenizer.sval);
        break;
    default:
        throw new WrongPhraseException("Unnexpected operator or operand: " + tokenizer.sval +".");
}
```

I give as input RPN, ex: 5 4 3 + *

Why is + not treated as TT_WORD, it isn't treated as it so it throws Exception.

Comment: What makes you think it should be treated as a word?

Comment: ok sry for messing up, i mislead myself with another class I wanted to use - String tokenizer. no Comment ;) however someone may find that link useful :) 
http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/java.io.StreamTokenizer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`StreamTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html#ttype) documentation:

> For a single character token, its value is the single character, converted to an integer.

Since your `+` character is single character, it is probably being treated as `TT_NUMBER`; your case statement for `TT_NUMBER` will need to handle these cases as well.  The same will apply for your unquoted `*` character as well, I assume.  Thus you might try something like this:

```
case StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER:
    Double value = new Double(tokenizer.nval);

    if (Character.isDigit(value.intValue()) {
        operands.add(value.doubleValue());

    } else {
        // Possibly dealing with operator here.  The hard/fun part is
        // in coercing that double value back to its tokenized string
        // form.
        operate(new Character((char) tokenizer.nval).toString());
    }

    break;
```

Hope this helps!